# add a key value in an array

Tags: php

I have

```
$test = array();

if(isset($ln[8])){
    $test[] .= $id[0].'=>'.$ln[14];
}
```

But it  puts the array like this

```
array (
           [0]=> 6525 => 120
           [1]=> 6521 => 1243
           [2]=> 5214 => 1674
           [3]=> 6528 => 155
)
```

whereas I want it to do this

```
array (
           6525 => 120
           6521 => 1243
           5214 => 1674
           6528 => 155
)
```

How would I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is adding *a string* consisting of, e.g., "6525 => 120" to each element in the array. What you really want to do is add the value from $lan[14] (e.g., the integer value 120) to the position $id[0] (e.g., 6525). This is how you do that with regular array syntax:

```
$test[$id[0]] = $ln[14];
```

Note how I treat `$id[0]` as the key to the `$test` array. It could have been the integer `6265`, a string with value `"hello"`, a variable called `$key`, a function call, or in this case an element from another array.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make the `$id[0]` the index, whereas currently you are concatenating a string together as the value.

Try the following:

```
$test[$id[0]] = $ln[14];
```

I'd also encourage you to look at [CakePHP's Set Class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1487/Set).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$test[$id[0]] = $ln[14];
```

Your mistake is that you try to append a string to the array and you have to use the `id` as a key and the `ln` as a value.