# Add key value to array without triggering an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669443/add-a-key-value-in-an-array), but if I assign a key-value pair to an empty array lik this

```
$arr[$key] = $value;
```

I get the php notice

```
Notice: Undefined index: <key> in <path>
```

where of course `<key>` is whatever value was in $key. 
How can I assign a value to a new key, without triggering a Notice?

Thanks!

edit: heres your more precise code. This is exactly whats in my code. Does this any difference?

```
while( list( $k, $sum ) = mysql_fetch_row( $res ) ) {
   if( $sum < 0 ) {
    $churn[$k] += $sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: and where exactly var $key gets its value? and why [$value] is in square brackets?

Comment: Are you assigning variables like this: `$arr['foo']='bar';` ? That is the proper way to do this...

Comment: sorry, the brackets around the $value where a typo, I don't have them in my code..

Comment: Add a real example and real error message, paraphrasing code and error messages is quite unproductive - there's nothing wrong with `$arr[$key] = $value;`

Comment: AD7six there is your more precise code example, which is from my code, just c&p. So, why do i get the error message, which is also precisly from my output, just replaced the key and the path with placeholders.

Comment: where key is a 2-3 char string, and path of course is the path of my .php

Answer (score 2):

declare your array before addind the key

```
$arr = array();
$arr[$key] = $value;
```

or simply do

```
$arr = array($key=>$value);
```

Comment: except declaring an array before using it is entirely unnecessary and not the mistake @nareille has made

Comment: i declared the array before, and the brackets were a typo, that i don't have in my code. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean `[$value]`

You're trying to get the value of a brand new array with a given key

Comment: Sebas, sorry, the brackets where a typo

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isnt correct. Just try my quick testcase which wont throw any notice.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $array = array();
    $key = 'new_key';
    $value = 'new_value';
    $array[$key] = $value;

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($array);
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem layed in

```
while( list( $k, $sum ) = mysql_fetch_row( $res ) ) {
   if( $sum < 0 ) {
   $churn[$k] += $sum;
  }   
}
```

due to the += operator. The first time, it gets called, churn['whateverWasIn$k'] is not set. The second time is fine though.. So to get rid of the notices, it has to be like:

```
(!isset($churn[$k])) ? $churn[$k] = $sum :  $churn[$k] += $sum;
```

Realize the missing + in the middle statement. So if this key does not exist by the time, i want to increase it by $sum, declare it and give it the value of $sum, otherwise just add $sum to the current value.

That's all. It doesn't look to pretty in code, but it gets me rid of 200 notices. Which also doesn't look too nice in my view.

Thanks for your help.